# Correctly push to an array that has been passed as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

### I Defined an array.

Then passed the array to the Console child as props.
`main.js`

```
class Main extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.moduleArray = [];
    this.state = {
      moduleArray: this.moduleArray
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="builder-root">
        <Console moduleArray={this.moduleArray} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
}
export default Main;
```

### I assigned the array to a `const`

Then onClick I am passing a parameter to the `append` function which runs a switch statement. Then I push the content of the matching case to the array. 
`console.js`

```
class Console extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { moduleArray } = this.props;
    const append = x => e => {
      switch (x) {
        case 0:
          console.log("case0");
          moduleArray.push(
            <div
              key={moduleArray.length}
              id={moduleArray.length}
              style={{ fontSize: 0, lineHeight: 0 }}
            >
              <Mod1 />
            </div>
          );
          console.log("pushed");
          break;
        //other switch cases
        default:
      }
      this.setState({
        moduleArray: this.moduleArray
      });
    };
    return (
      <div id="console">
        <input onClick={append(0)} value="Single col" type="submit" />
        //other clicks passing parameters
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Console;
```

And..... nothing happens. Well I say nothing. The function runs and prints the console logs out and I don't get an error. But the content doesn't render.

I think I need to use the `spread` operator in some way but I am unsure and struggling to find any reading material on a scenario like this.

Comment: In your logic case, you should receive the props and render them and change the state of the *parent component only* because of the immutability principle, just like Felix's answer is saying

Comment: How you are using `moduleArray` in `main.js` component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Console` component only renders, if its props or state is changing. Props can only be changed by the parent of the component. State is a component internal object which is changed by the component itself (but might depend on props or other calculations).

And Props are immutable. This means you can't overwrite them by

```
moduleArray.push(
            <div
              key={moduleArray.length}
              id={moduleArray.length}
              style={{ fontSize: 0, lineHeight: 0 }}
            >
              <Mod1 />
            </div>
          );
```

You even declared `moduleArray` as `const`. Change `moduleArray` in the parent of your component (through callback function) or initialize the state with the component's props and change the state with `this.setState(/*...*/)`.

A possible solution is listed below:

```
class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            moduleArray: [] // initialize empty or use props to init state
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // example
        // this.setState({moduleArray: serverResponse.modules}
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="builder-root">
                <Console moduleArray={this.state.moduleArray} addModule={(module) => this.setState({
                    moduleArray: [
                        ...this.state.moduleArray,
                        module
                    ]
                })}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
}
export default Main;
```

```
class Console extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {
            moduleArray,
            addModule
        } = this.props;


        const append = x => e => {
            switch (x) {
                case 0:

                    addModule(
                        <div
                            key={moduleArray.length}
                            id={moduleArray.length}
                            style={{fontSize: 0, lineHeight: 0}}
                        >
                            <Mod1/>
                        </div>
                    );

                    break;
                //other switch cases
                default:
            }
        };
        return (
            <div id="console">
                <input onClick={append(0)} value="Single col" type="submit"/>
                {/*other clicks passing parameters*/}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Console;
```